# Double ExpansionTile

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to write filters with categories and subcategories which can be in the form of a drop down list. I wrote this with an ExpansionTile, and put a Checkbox in the title of the ExpansionTile. And I ran into the problem that the Checkbox for subcategories works, but the Checkbox for the category does not work. Those. when you click on a category, subcategories open / close. But if you click on the Checkbox in the category, then nothing happens. Take a look.

[image]

How can I fix the problem so that the Checkbox in the category reacts to clicks.

```
class FilterDialogUser extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function(Map<String, List<String>?>) onApplyFilters;

  final Map<String, List<String>?> initialState;

  const FilterDialogUser({
    Key? key,
    required this.onApplyFilters,
    this.initialState = const {},
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FilterDialogUser> createState() => _FilterDialogUserState();
}

class _FilterDialogUserState extends State<FilterDialogUser> {
  Map<String, List<String>?> filters = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    filters = widget.initialState;
  }

  void _handleCheckFilter(bool checked, String key, String value) {
    final currentFilters = filters[key] ?? [];


    if (checked) {
      currentFilters.add(value);
    } else {
      currentFilters.remove(value);
    }
    setState(() {
      filters[key] = currentFilters;
    });
  }


  final countries = [
    Country(
      name: 'Germany',
      cars: [
        Car(name: 'Audi'),
        Car(name: 'BMW'),
        Car(name: 'Volkswagen'),
      ],
    ),
    Country(
      name: 'Sweden',
      cars: [
        Car(name: 'Koenigsegg'),
        Car(name: 'Polestar'),
        Car(name: 'Volvo'),
      ],
    ),
    Country(
      name: 'Russian',
      cars: [
        Car(name: 'GAZ'),
        Car(name: 'Lada'),
        Car(name: 'ZAZ'),
      ],
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SimpleDialog(
        title: const Text('Filters',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 25,
              fontFamily: 'SuisseIntl',
            )),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        children: [
          Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                for (Country country in countries)
                  ExpansionTile(
                      tilePadding: EdgeInsets.zero,

                      childrenPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                      title: CustomCheckboxTile(
                        value:

                            filters['country']?.contains(country.name) ?? false,
                        onChange: (check) =>
                            _handleCheckFilter(check, 'country', country.name),
                        label: country.name,
                      ),
                      initiallyExpanded: () {
                        for (final Car car in country.cars) {
                          if (filters['cars']?.contains(car.name) ?? false) {
                            return true;
                          }
                        }
                        return false;
                      }(),
                      children: [
                        for (Car car in country.cars)
                          CustomCheckboxTile(
                            value: filters['cars']?.contains(car.name) ?? false,
                            onChange: (check) =>
                                _handleCheckFilter(check, 'cars', car.name),
                            label: car.name,
                          )
                      ])
              ]),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                widget.onApplyFilters(filters);
              },
              child: const Text('APPLY', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.grey),
              )),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                setState(() {
                  filters.clear();
                });
                widget.onApplyFilters(filters);
              },
              child: const Text('RESET FILTERS',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.grey),
              )),
        ]);
  }
}

class Country {
  Country({
    required this.name,
    this.isChecked = false,
    this.cars = const [],
  });

  final String name;
  final List<Car> cars;
  final bool isChecked;

  bool get isAllCarsChecked => cars.every((car) => car.isChecked);

  bool get isAllChecked => isAllCarsChecked && isChecked;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Country(name: $name, isChecked: $isChecked, cars: $cars)';
  }
}

class Car {
  Car({required this.name, this.isChecked = false});

  final String name;
  final bool isChecked;



  @override
  String toString() => 'Car(name: $name, isChecked: $isChecked)';
}
```

custom_checkbox_tile.dart

```
    class CustomCheckboxTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final bool value;
  final void Function(bool)? onChange;

  const CustomCheckboxTile({Key? key,
    required this.label, required this.value, this.onChange,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Checkbox(
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
          value: value,
          onChanged: (_) {
            if(onChange != null) {
              onChange!(!value);
            }
          },
        ),
        Text(label),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide simplified version of code, it is missing widgets like `CustomCheckboxTile` and `SimpleDialog`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I have added code for CustomCheckboxTile. and you can read about SimpleDialog on the Internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete example. For me, it is easier and cleaner to handle large data with `ValueNotifier` than with `setState`. You can use this code or customize it how you want. Copy and paste to the [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=e75b493dae1287757c5e1d77a0dc73f1) to find your answer.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Initial data. It can be loaded from the local or remote database.
    final countries = [
      Country(
        name: 'Germany',
        cars: [
          Car(name: 'Audi'),
          Car(name: 'BMW'),
          Car(name: 'Volkswagen'),
        ],
      ),
      Country(
        name: 'Sweden',
        cars: [
          Car(name: 'Koenigsegg'),
          Car(name: 'Polestar'),
          Car(name: 'Volvo'),
        ],
      ),
      Country(
        name: 'Russian',
        cars: [
          Car(name: 'GAZ'),
          Car(name: 'Lada'),
          Car(name: 'ZAZ'),
        ],
      ),
    ];

    // It's simple Provider for passing value down in the widget tree.
    // And will keep you data until app will be killed or `Provider` will be removed from the widget tree.
    // If you use Provider package the you dont need it.
    return Provider(
      value: CountryController(countries), // Add to the controller.
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Checkbox Expansion Tile Demo',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const Home(title: 'Checkbox Expansion Tile Demo'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const Home({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Call value from the above widget tree.
    final controller = Provider.of<CountryController>(context);
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ValueListenableBuilder<List<Country>>(
          valueListenable: controller,
          builder: (context, countries, _) => Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              for (Country country in countries)
                ExpansionTile(
                  title: Text(country.name),
                  leading: Checkbox(
                    value: country.isAllCarsChecked,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      //controller.checkCountry(country.name);
                      controller.checkAllByCountry(country.name, value);
                    },
                  ),
                  children: [
                    for (Car car in country.cars)
                      CustomCheckboxTile(
                        title: car.name,
                        value: car.isChecked,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          controller.checkCar(car.name);
                        },
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  controller.checkAll(true);
                },
                child: const Text('CHECK ALL'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  controller.checkAll(false);
                },
                child: const Text('RESET ALL'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print(countries);
                },
                child: const Text('PRINT ALL'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomCheckboxTile extends ListTile {
  CustomCheckboxTile({
    Key? key,
    required String title,
    required bool value,
    double leftPadding = 28.0,
    ValueChanged<bool?>? onChanged,
  }) : super(
          key: key,
          title: Text(title),
          leading: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: leftPadding),
            child: Checkbox(
              value: value,
              onChanged: onChanged,
            ),
          ),
        );
}

class Country {
  Country({
    required this.name,
    this.cars = const [],
  });

  final String name;
  final List<Car> cars;

  bool get isAllCarsChecked => cars.every((car) => car.isChecked);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Country(name: $name, cars: $cars)';
  }
}

class Car {
  Car({required this.name, this.isChecked = false});

  final String name;
  final bool isChecked;

  @override
  String toString() => 'Car(name: $name, isChecked: $isChecked)';
}

class CountryController extends ValueNotifier<List<Country>> {
  CountryController(List<Country>? countries) : super(countries ?? const []);

  void checkCountry(String countryName) {
    value = [
      for (var country in value)
        if (country.name == countryName)
          Country(
            name: country.name,
            cars: country.cars,
          )
        else
          country
    ];
  }

  void checkCar(String carName) {
    value = [
      for (var country in value)
        Country(
          name: country.name,
          cars: [
            for (var car in country.cars)
              if (car.name == carName)
                Car(
                  name: car.name,
                  isChecked: !car.isChecked,
                )
              else
                car
          ],
        ),
    ];
  }

  void checkAllByCountry(String countryName, bool? isChecked) {
    if (isChecked == null) return;

    value = [
      for (var country in value)
        if (country.name == countryName)
          Country(
            name: country.name,
            cars: [
              for (var car in country.cars)
                Car(
                  name: car.name,
                  isChecked: isChecked,
                ),
            ],
          )
        else
          country
    ];
  }

  void checkAll(bool? isChecked) {
    value = [
      for (var country in value)
        Country(
          name: country.name,
          cars: [
            for (var car in country.cars)
              Car(
                name: car.name,
                isChecked: isChecked ?? false,
              ),
          ],
        ),
    ];
  }
}
```

#### Simple value provider

```dart
class Provider<T> extends StatelessWidget {
  const Provider({
    Key? key,
    required this.value,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final T value;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _InheritedWidget<T>(
      value: value,
      child: child,
    );
  }

  static T of<T>(BuildContext context) {
    return context
        .dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_InheritedWidget<T>>()!
        .value;
  }
}

class _InheritedWidget<T> extends InheritedWidget {
  const _InheritedWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.value,
    required Widget child,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  final T value;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(_InheritedWidget<T> oldWidget) {
    return oldWidget.value != value;
  }
}
```

#### Countries Inherited Widget

```dart
class CountriesProvider extends InheritedWidget {
  const CountriesProvider({
    Key? key,
    required this.countries,
    required Widget child,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  final List<Country> countries;

  static List<Country> of(BuildContext context) {
    final result =
        context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<CountriesProvider>();

    if (result == null) {
      debugPrint(
        'Returned empty countries list due to not found CountriesProvider in the above widget tree.',
      );
    }

    return result?.countries ?? [];
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(CountriesProvider oldWidget) {
    return oldWidget.countries != countries;
  }
}

// Usage:
    //...
    return CountriesProvider(
      countries: countries, // Add countries list.
      child: MaterialApp(
    //...

    // Call countries from the above widget tree.
    final countries = CountriesProvider.of(context);
    // Add to the controller.
    final controller = CountryController(countries);
```

#### Update

Added check all and reset all buttons.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think this is a good solution, I can check it later. Only I have one small question: when the user selects a category, then all the elements of the subcategory are automatically selected, but if the user deselects any element of the subcategory, I would like the checkmark from the category to be removed (since the search in the database will only be carried out by cities ). Can you help finish this?

Comment: Ok, I will fix it as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I have accepted your answer. You are a great programmer! Only my request from the first comment does not work: I would like to make it so that if the user unchecks at least one subcategory, then the checkmark would also disappear from the category

Comment: Please forgive me, but in my code there was a _handleCheckFilter function that allowed me to store the state of the selected items when the filter window was closed (i.e. if the user ticks and closes the filter window or clicks apply filters, the state of the checkboxes is saved the next time it is opened.) Is it possible how -something to add _handleCheckFilter to your code?

Comment: Updated to your preferences. To filter list you need filter value in the `County` class `isAllCarsChecked`. Ex: `if(isAllCarsChecked) remove(country) else remove(car);` Just play with it and test.

Comment: Remember `ValueNotifier` keeps your value data in the memory until you do not remove him from the widget tree. Add as you see in my example I added a print button. Print button print all updated data and you can do what you want and filter how you want with all data. Or you need help to filter result list?

Comment: No, I don't need help with filtering. I meant that in my code there is a functionality that allows you to save the state of the checkboxes after the filter window is closed (i.e. for example, if the filter window is closed and reopened, then if the checkboxes were checked, then this does not disappear, but is saved ). I did it with _handleCheckFilter. Can this function be added to your code somehow?

Comment: Of course, it is possible. You need just save the state of the `CountryController` and load it in the next load. But how do you want to save it and use it, I need to know how you want to save it. You want save it to local with shared_preferences for example or keep it checked boxes until the app will be killed.

Comment: Yes, save locally. If the application or page closes there is no need to store data anymore

Comment: Haha. Locally its means when the user kill the app on the next load all saved data will be restored. But how I understand you, you want keep the state in the memory until the app will be killed. I will update the code with some useful tools to hold your checked buttons until the app will be killed. It can be for the advanced, but everything can be learned.

Comment: No, I meant that the state of the checkboxes should be kept until the page is reloaded. (Downtime, I use the SimpeDialog widget, and I don't have to reload the page to open the filter window.)

Comment: I understand what you want. I updated my example, you can test and see. I hope this is not very difficult.

Comment: I have seen. I will check a little later and write to you. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243895/discussion-between-arnas-and-).